# Hadoop: Is it possible to have in memory structures in map function and aggregate them?

Tags: java, memory, data-structures, hadoop, mapreduce

I am currently reading a paper and i have come to a point were the writers say that they have some arrays in memory for every map task and when the map task ends, they output that array.

This is the paper that i am referring to : http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36296.html

This looks somewhat a bit non-mapreduce thing to do, but i am trying to implement this project and i have come to a point were this is the only solution. I have tried many ways to use the common map reduce philosophy, which is process each line and output a key-value pair, but in that way i have for every line of input many thousands of context writes and its takes a long time to write them. So my map task is a bottleneck. These context writes cost a lot.

If i do it their way, i will have managed to reduce the number of key-value pairs dramatically. So i need to find a way to have in memory structures for every map task. 
I can define these structures as static in the setup function, but i can find a way to tell when the map tasks ends, so that i can output that structure. I know it sounds a bit weird, but it is the only way to work efficiently.

This is what they say in that paper

> On startup, each mapper loads the set of split points to be
>   considered for each ordered attribute. For each node n ∈ N
>   and attribute X, the mapper maintains a table Tn,X of key-
>   value pairs.
>
> After processing all input data, the mappers out-
>   put keys of the form n, X and value v, Tn,X [v]

Here are some edits after Sean's answer :

I am using a combiner in my job. The thing is that these context.write(Text,Text) commands in my map function, are really time consuming. My input is csv files or arff files. In every line there is an example. My examples might have up to thousands of attributes. I am outputting for every attribute, key-value pairs in the form <(n,X,u),Y>, where is the name of the node (i am building a decision tree), X is the name of the attribute, u is the value of the attribute and Y are some statistics in Text format. As you can tell, if i have 100,000 attributes, i will have to have 100,000 context.write(Text,Text) commands for every example. Running my map task without these commands, it runs like the wind. If i add the context.write command, it takes forever. Even for a 2,000 thousand attribute training set. It really seems like i am writing in files and not in memory. So i really need to reduce those writes. Aggregating them in memory (in map function and not in the combiner) is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a different answer since I see the point of the question now I think.

To know when the map task ends, well, you can override `close()`. I don't know if this is what you want. If you have 50 mappers, the 1/50th of the input each sees is not known or guaranteed. Is that OK for your use case -- you just need each worker to aggregate stats in memory for what it has seen and output?

Then your procedure is fine but probably would not make your in-memory data structure `static` -- nobody said two `Mapper`s won't run in one JVM classloader.

A more common version of this pattern plays out in the `Reducer` where you need to collect info over some known subset of the keys coming in before you can produce one record. You can use a partitioner, and the fact the keys are sorted, to know you are seeing all of that subset on one worker, and, can know when it's done because a new different subset appears. Then it's pretty easy to collect data in memory while processing a subset, output the result and clear it when a new subset comes in.

I am not sure that works here since the bottleneck happens before the `Reducer`.

Comment: yes this is exactly what i want. aggregate and output to the reducer (and maybe have a combiner). Close seems like a good solution. And yes by having static variables can cause some problems. Thanks for pointing that out. So i will try to do something like context.write inside close( i just checked it is called cleanup). I will inform you if that worked. I just tried writing some smaller Text variables and it went kinda faster. Thanks for both of your answers. They couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: Ok i did it. This is totally the way the paper describes it. It goes a lot faster. I still need to optimize my code a bit and it will be fine. Thanks a lot for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing a bit more about the details of what you are outputting, I can't be certain if this will help, but, this sounds like exactly what a combiner is designed to help with. It is like a miniature reducer (in fact, a combiner implementation is just another implementation of `Reducer`) attached to the output of a `Mapper`. Its purpose is to collect map output records in memory, and try to aggregate them before being written to disk and then collected by the `Reducer`.

The classic example is counting values. You can output "key,1" from your map and then add up the 1s in a reducer, but, this involves outputting "key,1" 1000 times from a mapper if the key appears 1000 times when "key,1000" would suffice. A combiner does that. Of course it only applies when the operation in question is associative/commutative and can be run repeatedly with no side effect -- addition is a good example.

Another answer: in Mahout we implement a lot of stuff that is both weird, a bit complex, and very slow if done the simple way. Pulling tricks like collecting data in memory in a `Mapper` is a minor and sometimes necessary sin, so, nothing really wrong with it. It does mean you really need to know the semantics that Hadoop guarantees, test well, and think about running out of memory if not careful.

Comment: Thanks Sean. See my edits for more information. I am using a combiner. By the way i have used Mahout and i have read your book. I can't wait to see some later versions :D .

Comment: (I assume you have map output compression on.) Maybe you can hash the names or features or the stats to some smaller identifier that can be reconstituted later? Or at least something more compact than a plain Text.

Comment: Well i didn't have the compression on, but i did now and nothing happened. It is not like i have a problem with the size of my Text variables, but with the number of writes. Isn't there any way to tell when a map task is about to end? Perhaps the Google implementation has a way of knowing that and is why the used it. I really appreciate your interest.